# EF Code first alongside database first

Tags: entity-framework

I'm a newbie when it comes to EF. Always used NHibernate and now I'm learning something new.

I've got a project in which everything was created using database first approach.

Is there a way to use Code first to go along with the database first ?

So that any changes to database will be visible in code but also so it would be possible to make changes to database  by changing existing/ creating new models?

Cheers!

Comment: No. You can create a CodeFirst model from a Database using the built-in tools, but you can't "keep in sync" changes from database and code as you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Code First to an Existing Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx) approach and for keep Database with models in sync and you can apply [Code First Migrations with an existing database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn579398) and for more info see channel9 video:

[Migrations - Existing Databases](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Existing-Databases)

Comment: But that won't keep subsequent changes in the database in sync with the codefirst model, would it? (if so, I'm interested!)

Comment: No it's one way, from model to database.

Comment: @mo.esmp so basically it's not possible :( I have to use one or another. Well that is just sad considering I prefer Code first much more whereas the developer that started the project wants to go with database first to apply all the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Code First From Existing Database to generate Code First from a database. This will most probably mean you will need to change to Code First for your DataContext to keep it in sync in code going forward.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx